# geopandas (python) generate a map from specific zone

Tags: python, geopandas

Im looking how to generate a coastline map from the entire Gulf of Mexico (GM). I'm trying to make a plot of the GM including on it results obtained from Metagenomics (abundance of each taxon). 
So I just want or know, how to extract a coast line using python, using the coordinates something like,  -90.5 to -73.7 and 32.4 to 16.3 (or any unit) to make the plot something like

[image]

Similar to the picture (without the grid).

I need the shapefile or any other file that could be plot with python using geopandas, or any other libraries. Or how to obtain the Shapefile from some online map (defining the zone, and export the data !!), any way to get the files or plot the specific zone ??

Thanks So Much !!

Comment: you obtain the shape file by finding a data provider and downloading the data. i would start with search terms along the lines of "world boundaries GIS data"

Comment: thanks, already found it, thanks !